# creating an application that can be called from command line or referenced how do I setup the call

Tags: c#

I need to create a desktop app in C# that will require a specific set of parameters when loaded, either by command line (or a direct reference?) from an old VB6 application or as a reference from a vb.net application.

I need parameters such as name, city, state, zip and a few others. I'm not sure yet what all I'll need yet. I know I'll need some very basic account information to be passed in.

What would be the best way to accept these parameters where they can be called from either application?

I started to create a class that contained the needed parameters, but I am not sure if a VB6 application can reference the exe as a dll and pass a it the class back. I've not called a .net application from vb6 so I don't know the requirements and I don't have vb6 installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write a DLL/library. Then write an EXE that takes the parameters and just references that DLL the same as other code would.

Comment: ah so make the dll work as a specific way but have the exe for the command line call to pass the required parameters! great idea!

Comment: you should put that as an answer so I can give you credit :)

Comment: Yes. Then you can reference the DLL wherever you want -- and also have the EXE "wrap" it, so you can use command line as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a DLL/library. Then write an EXE that takes the parameters and just references that DLL the same as other code would.

Answer (score 0):

This may help, Command Line Parameters Tutorial
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I'm familiar with command line parameters with c# but is that my only option in this case when using vb6?